# How can I make sure bar.com is always identical to foo.freedns.com?

Tags: dns

I'm in the situation where I have one address that's fairly reliable since it's being updated with a program on the server, that we can call `foo.freedns.com`. This DNS entry always has the correct IP for this reason. Then we have the manually configured `bar.com` which obviously will stop working as soon as the server IP address changes (which it will).

So what I'm wondering is, how can I make sure the DNS record for `bar.com` is identical to `foo.freedns.com` at all times? Can I simply create a DNS entry at the company that handles `bar.com` for me, and instead of redirecting it to the current IP, I redirect it to `foo.freedns.com`? I have a feeling this will not work, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot create a `CNAME` record for `bar.com`. `bar.com` is at a zone apex and must therefore have `SOA` and `NS` records. A DNS name cannot have a `CNAME` record together with any other type of record.

Your options are to switch to using a DNS name that isn't at a zone apex (e.g. `foo.bar.com`) and put a `CNAME` on that, or use dynamic DNS to update the `A` and `AAAA` records of `bar.com` whenever the addresses change.